# Relative entropy of complementary channel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy

Given a channel $N: A \rightarrow B$, assume there exist two quantum states $\rho, \sigma \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ (where $\mathcal{D}(A)$ refers to positive semidefinite operators with trace 1) that satisfy

$$D(N(\rho)||N(\sigma)) = D(\rho||\sigma),$$

where $D(A||B)$ is the [relative entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_relative_entropy) between $A$ and $B$. It is known (see slide 11 of [this presentation](http://www.markwilde.com/publications/reverse-cambridge.pdf)) that such an equality implies that there exists a recovery map $R_{\sigma, N}$ such that $R_{\sigma, N}(N(\rho)) = \rho$ and $R_{\sigma, N}(N(\sigma)) = \sigma$.

Is there anything that can be said of the relative entropy between $\rho$ and $\sigma$ after the [complementary channel](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/what-is-a-complementary-map) $N_c$ acts on them?

$$D(N_c(\rho)||N_c(\sigma)) = ?$$

**Partial attempts at an answer**

1) It is possible that $D(N_c(\rho)||N_c(\sigma)) = 0$ since we can simply assume that $N$ is a unitary transformation.

2) There is this intuition that the information is perfectly transmitted by the channel so the complementary channel should lose all the information so this might suggest that $D(N_c(\rho)||N_c(\sigma)) = 0$ always. But I'm not sure about this.

Comment: At least if $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are orthogonal, any value is possible for the complementary channel.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch could you add what channel you are using to construct such a counter example?

Comment: Two options: Either the identity, or the fully depolarizing channel: Their extension $V$ would map |0> and |1> either to |00> and |10>, or to |00> and |11>.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, sorry I'm not able to follow your argument. Let's say it's the identity channel - in this case the complementary channel is a constant channel i.e. $N_c(\rho) = \vert 0 \rangle \langle 0\vert$ for all $\rho$. Hence $D(N_c(\rho)||N_c(\sigma)) = 0$ always. If you use the fully depolarizing channel, then $D(N(\rho)||N(\sigma)) = 0$ always and hence to achieve $D(N(\rho)||N(\sigma)) = D(\rho||\sigma)$, you must set $\rho = \sigma$. Then, we again have $D(N_c(\rho)||N_c(\sigma)) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I mean the fully dephasing channel - the one with the stinespring dilation I gave above: V|0> = |00>, V|1> = |11>.  Clearly, the channel equals its complement.